# disambiguate base class name in class template

Tags: c++, logging

We have a logging framework which allows us to add **context specific information** automatically to log messages.

This is achieved by inheriting off `Context` class template which, using the `CRTP pattern` / `static polymorphism`, calls a `Token()` function on the subclass to obtain the object's context.

When logging we use a macro which expands to `GetLog()`.

- When inside a **member function** `GetLog` is found in the base class, which obtains the logger and adds the context `Token`.
- when inside a **free function** or **non-`Context`-derived class**, `GetLog` is found in the global namespace, and it just obtains the logger.

There is a fully working example below.

**Problem**

My problem is that if I have a class template which is in turn derived off `Context`, eg:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo : Context<Foo<T>>;
```

When I try to log inside a member function I have to prefix `LOG` with `this->` in order to make the method `GetLog()` a *dependent name*.

Is there any way I can have a **class template member function** use `LOG` without `this->` and have it resolve to `Context::GetLog()`?

**Thoughts**

- Make `Token` a virtual function and use dynamic polymorphism to get the context. Disadvantage is that this adds a v-table lookup on every logging call (with a lot of `Context` derived objects, would the compiler be able to inline?) I'd like to make this as lean as possible.
- Use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` to differentiate between `Context` and `non-Context` derived objects. I don't think I'd be able to get this to work with free functions though?
- Any other way?

Here is a working exemplar:

```
#include <iostream>

// stub logging object to make the example work - just logs to stdout
struct Log
{
    template<typename T>
    friend Log& operator<<(Log& l, T d)
    {
        std::cout << d;
        return l;
    }
    friend Log& operator<<(Log& l, std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream&))
    {
        std::cout << f;
        return l;
    }
};
Log gLog;

#define LOG GetLog()

// GetLog in the global namespace for non-Context derived classes, free functions etc
Log& GetLog()
{
    return gLog;
}

// classes derive from this to add context specific information when logging
template<typename Self>
struct Context
{
    // this GetLog adds prefix to Context derived classes
    Log& GetLog()
    {
        static_cast<const Self*>(this)->Token(gLog); // add the Context's Token to the log
        return gLog << ": ";
    }
};

//-------------------------

template<typename T>
struct Foo : Context<Foo<T>>
{
    void Func1()
    {
        LOG << __func__ << std::endl;       // resolves to the global GetLog() free-function
    }
    void Func2()
    {
        this->LOG << __func__ << std::endl; // notice the 'this->' prefix to make GetLog() a dependent name
    }

    Log& Token(Log& l) const { return l << "Foo"; }
};

// logging inside a non-Context derived class
struct Bar
{
    void Func()
    {
        LOG << __func__ << std::endl;
    }
};

// logging inside a free function 
void Baz()
{
    LOG << __func__ << std::endl;
}

//-------------------------

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    f.Func1();
    f.Func2();

    Bar b;
    b.Func();

    Baz();

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Note: the `exit` call is unnecessary, if you wish to be explicit you would be using `return 0;` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly bring `Context::GetLog` into the scope of the derived class with a *using declaration:*

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo : Context<Foo<T>>
{
    using Context<Foo<T>>::GetLog;

    // the rest as before
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/lqJ2uP)

Comment: Even more lightweight than my solution; although both suffer from the same issue (in my eyes): there is no compile-time error if you forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a simple solution, though it will require some additional work in Context-derived classes.

You can use qualification by the base-class name instead of `this->`, so for example using `Context<Foo<T>>::GetLog` is sufficient to indicate to the compiler that the look-up is dependent (and must be delayed until instantiation).

Unfortunately, since `Context` is itself a template, it's a bit of a bore; so instead we'll be using another class (I call it `Base` here):

```
// 1. Wrap the generic GetLog into a `Base` class:
struct Base {
    static Log& GetLog() { return glog; }
};

// 2. Introduce a typedef into the derived class:
template <typename T>
struct Foo: Context<Foo<T>> {
    typedef Context<Foo<T>> Base;

    ...
};

// 3. Change the macro
#define LOG Base::GetLog()
```

Here, the `Base` lookup obeys the typical scope rules, and the nearest `Base` is found... which default to the one existing in the global scope in the worst case.

The fully working demo is at [ideone](http://ideone.com/KzVNZu).